PSTricks web site gallery issue?
I'm trying to compile all figures available on the PSTricks website here:
https://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples-list
However they all fail to compile on my computer and on Overleaf.
Any idea why?
PS: I have contacted the administrator of the website but didn't get any answer yet.

Which engine do you use to compile your documents? Seems to work fine on overleaf with latex (you can change it in the left hand menu): https://www.overleaf.com/read/rdshhfcdcqgt#404266

Indeed! It was an engine choice issue. They all seem to work only with XeLaTeX. Didn't know that. Thanks a lot

They work with latex, too!

And were you able to run the PowerPlant example .... ?
https://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Physics/AKW.tex

works fine https://www.overleaf.com/read/rsssjgsfshyk#9baf0e

That's crazy! It doesn't work on my Overleaf. I will try to investigate why.

Compare the engine and texlive version

Yep i tried same you: Live 2024 and all four different engines but all fail. I will try again tomorrow. This makes me headache.

Maybe try to open a new project and test if it works there?

And i'm curious while i'm trying for the powerplant.... can you try that one too with your Overleaf please? https://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery/exa049.tex

Works fine with TL2020

If one removes some of the font packages, it even compiles with TL'24

And now it's a font package issue... Argh! I feel the path will be long to make all of them work on my machine................. Thanks for your time!
